# Reflection of a <table> control

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a login page that has the login fields in the middle, in a . How can I create a reflection effect of this table? I would like to have under this square at a little distance another one just like it, but only the background to show, not the controls too. So I have tried to make under it another table, but I want to show of it only about 10%. Can this be done?

This is as far as I got, have tried it with gradients, but doesn't look very good:

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
           <table>
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="loginContent">
                         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="rightContent">
                         </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="lineBreak15">
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="loginContentReflection">
                     </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


.loginContent 
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #f08409;
}
.loginContentReflection 
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,204,2,0.3) 0%, rgba(248,211,64,0.3) 28%, rgba(233,224,187,0) 84%, rgba(229,228,222,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,204,2,0.3)), color-stop(28%,rgba(248,211,64,0.3)), color-stop(84%,rgba(233,224,187,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(229,228,222,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,204,2,0.3) 0%,rgba(248,211,64,0.3) 28%,rgba(233,224,187,0) 84%,rgba(229,228,222,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,204,2,0.3) 0%,rgba(248,211,64,0.3) 28%,rgba(233,224,187,0) 84%,rgba(229,228,222,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,204,2,0.3) 0%,rgba(248,211,64,0.3) 28%,rgba(233,224,187,0) 84%,rgba(229,228,222,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,204,2,0.3) 0%,rgba(248,211,64,0.3) 28%,rgba(233,224,187,0) 84%,rgba(229,228,222,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4dffcc02', endColorstr='#00e5e4de',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code of what you have tried?

Comment: ok, I have edited it, hope it helps

Comment: Why are you doing this in a table? It makes it a lot harder.

Comment: because I didn't think of something else, I am opened to sugestions. Thanks.